# Is it a bad idea to have a web browser query another api instead of my site providing it?

Tags: api, yql

Here's my issue.  I have a site that provides some investing services, I pay for end of day data which is all I really need for my service but I feel its a bit odd when people check in during the day and it only displays yesterdays closing price.  End of day is fine for my analytics but I want to display delayed quotes on my site.

According to the yahoo's [YQL faq](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq/): `If you use IP based authentication then you are limited to 1000 calls/day/IP`, if my site grows I may exceed that but I was thinking of trying to push this request to the people browsing my site themselves since its extremely unlikely that the same IP will visit my site 1,000 times a day(my site itself has no use for this info). I would call a url from their browser, then parse the results so I can allow them to view it in the format of the sites template.

I'm new to web development so I'm wondering is it a common practice or a bad idea to have the users browser make the api call themselves?

Comment: The FAQ also says that you can make 100,000 calls/day/key if OAuth based authentication is used. How to generate and register the OAuth key can be found [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html). If 100,000 calls/day is fine then that should solve your issue.

Comment: @KaranAshar it's more than enough for now but I figured if I could push the limit to the users then I'll never have to worry about it because if a user goes beyond the limit they will only impact themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bad idea at all:

- You stretch up limitations this way;
- Your server will respond faster (since it does not have to contact the api);
- Your page will load faster because the initial response is smaller;
- You can load the remaining data from the api in async manner while your UI is already responsive.

Generally speaking it is a great idea to talk with api's from the client. It's more dynamic, you spread traffic, more responsiveness etc...

The biggest downside I can think of is depending on the availability of other services. On the other hand your server(s) will be stressed less because of spreading the traffic.

Hope this helped a bit! Cheers!